# Using Jumpers wires in an Electronic design

Tags: jumper

I am working on a design, but still in the prototype stage. In any case, I am using a straight Vero board and hence quite a lot of Jumper cables are involved even to its bearest minimum. I want to know the effect of the Jumpers when they are much? Actually my design is not actually behaving well as it ought to, so I am kind of thinking it my be as a result of this. It involves using MAx232 to transmit data's between a GSM module and microcontroller.

And if there is possible an effect of jumpers, then how can I reduce it to a bearable minimum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RS-232 will be running comparatively slowly. Provided the MAX232 is properly decoupled and the connections are kept short the number of jumpers shouldn't matter. You probably have a wiring error with the capacitors; I prefer the MAX202 to the MAX232 as the former uses 100 nF ceramic capacitors. I never use Veroboard and often make my own prototype PCBs at home, I have a useful little board with a MAX202 on it that I can connect to anything that needs RS-232 conversion.